# Add default headers for every request in httpie

Tags: httpie

I need to be able to either set in my httpie/config.json file to include some default headers (these are custom headers and not normal ones) to every request that i send from httpie by default (ALWAYS)

ie:
headers examples

```
http "http://poopskiesuprise.com" 'CUSTOM_HEADER:asdf' 'HEADER_TWO:asdf'
```

always include the 'CUSTOM_HEADER' and 'HEADER_TWO'
to every request so i can just do this

```
http "http://poopskiesuprise.com"
```

i did not see a good way to do this in the documentation so any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is creating a session with desired headers, and using it on your `config.json`:

Create a [session](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/sessions) (for your desired host):

```
$ http --session ./session.json pie.dev/get X-Custom-Header:value X-Custom-Header2:value2
```

and then add this to your [config](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/config) (`~/.config/httpie/config.json` on POSIX):

```
{
    "default_options": [
        "--session-read-only=/path/to/session.json"
    ]
}
```

and then from now on, every request will add those two headers:

```
$ http pie.dev/get

{
    "args": {},
    "headers": {
        "X-Custom-Header": "value",
        "X-Custom-Header2": "value2"
    },
    "url": "http://pie.dev/get"
}
```

Unless you [unset](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/empty-headers-and-header-un-setting) them:

```
$ http pie.dev/get X-Custom-Header:

{
    "args": {},
    "headers": {
        "X-Custom-Header2": "value2"
    },
    "url": "http://pie.dev/get"
}
```